# Владимир Путин: Не мы движемся к НАТО, а оно - к нам. Как рассматривать эту запись с точки зрения синтаксиса?

Tags: синтаксис, прямая-речь, синтаксический-разбор, члены-предложения, заголовок

Часто в заголовках (и не только) встречается запись, в которой сначала приводится имя автора высказывания, а затем после двоеточия дается сама цитата (в кавычках или без них). Иногда цитата начинается с заглавной буквы, иногда - со строчной.
Вот несколько примеров, найти которые не составило труда:
[пример №1](http://www.aif.ru/politics/world/putin_otnosheniya_s_turciey_priobretayut_bolee_soderzhatelnyy_harakter),
[пример №2](https://www.kp.ru/daily/26872.4/3914641/),
[пример №3](https://pozneronline.ru/2018/08/22308/).

Можно ли считать имя автора высказывания в данном случае предложением в составе конструкции с прямой речью? Если да, то каким предложением: неполным или номинативным? Или это именительный темы (представления)? Или же это особый случай, где существительное в именительном падеже используется для указания автора высказывания, и о предложении нельзя вести речь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобные примеры относятся т.н. сегментированным конструкциям. Существует несколько видов сегментированных конструкций( сюда также относится и ИТ). Пример, который вы приводите, Н.С. Валгина относит к конструкциям с именительным разъяснительно-пояснительным. Такие конструкции распространены в газетных заголовках. Глвное отличие ИТ от конструкций с с именительным разъяснительно-пояснительными отношениями заключается в том, что " Постсегментный компонент в конструкциях с именительным разъяснительно-пояснительным, в отличие от именительного темы, во-первых, не имеет в своем составе коррелята, во-вторых, может быть выражен любой синтаксической единицей: от синтаксемы до сложного предложения, а также единицей более высокого уровня — сложным синтаксическим целым:

> **1) синтаксема: Метро: перезагрузка (Аргументы и факты. — 2003.- № 25);**
>
> **2) словосочетание*: Трагедия в казарме: истоки и уроки (Магнитогорский металл. - 2006. - № 13); Героин: диагноз горя (Комсомольская правда. - 2004. -21 апреля);**

6) сложное синтаксическое целое: **Лариса Удовиченко: крутые люди в Голливуде? Нагни лучше (Телесемь. — 2003.— № 38).**

Подробнее вы можете ознакомиться здесь:[Сегментированные конструкции в современном русском языке](http://cheloveknauka.com/segmentirovannye-konstruktsii-v-sovremennom-russkom-yazyke#ixzz5PsDNF4Vd)

Answer (score 0):

Да, особый случай, и о предложении нельзя вести речь. Примерно как в тексте пьесы.